# Use paramater value in a custom class (Symfony2)

Tags: php, symfony

I have some parameter values in app/config/parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: database_name
    ...
    igv: 0.18
    isc: 0.18
```

Now, I want to use the parameters in a Custom class in AppBundle/CustomClass.php. How can I use this parameters? I try $this->container->get('igv') but not works.

Comment: does your custom class extend ContainerAware? Either make it do that or if it is defined as a service, inject just the parameter

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In services.yml:

```
my_app.customclass:
    class:  AppBundle\CustomClass
    arguments: ['%igv%', '%isc%']
```

Add the arguments to the constructor of AppBundle\CustomClass.

Comment: You're welcome.  The documentation on use of parameters is [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html).